# How to group array based on the same values

Tags: python, arrays, django, sparql, ontology

Please, confused with array in python. I want to group array based on the same values.

Code:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUN30.png)

```
id_disease = ['penyakit_tepung','hawar_daun']
for id_disease in id_disease:
    qres = acacia.query( 
        """
        PREFIX tst: <http://www.semanticweb.org/aalviian/ontologies/2017/1/untitled-ontology-10#>
        SELECT ?disease ?patogen
        WHERE { 
            ?disease tst:caused_by ?patogen . 
            FILTER regex(str(?disease), "%s") .
        } """ % id_disease )

    for row in qres:
        for r in row:
            print(r.replace('http://www.semanticweb.org/aalviian/ontologies/2017/1/untitled-ontology-10#',''))
        print("\n")
```

Output:

```
penyakit_tepung
spaerotheca_sp

penyakit_tepung
oidium_sp


penyakit_tepung
erysiphe_sp


hawar_daun
cylindrocladium_sp


hawar_daun
kirramyces_sp


hawar_daun
phaeophleopspora_sp
```

Expected Array :

```
[['spaeerotheca_sp','oidium_sp','erysiphe_sp'].['cylindrocladium_sp','kirramyces_sp','phaeophleopspora_sp']]
```

Please, help me if you know how step to get it.

Comment: Please copy and paste your code directly into your question, and do not take screenshots. It makes it easier for us to try out your code on our machines.

Comment: Edited :)
Thank you for ur suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
listoflists = []

for row in qres:
    a_list = []

        for r in row:
           data = r.replace('http://www.semanticweb.org/aalviian/ontologies/2017/1/untitled-ontology-10#','')
           a_list.append(data)

    listoflists.append(a_list)

print listoflists
```

Comment: The output like this:

`[['penyakit_tepung', 'oidium_sp'], ['penyakit_tepung', 'erysiphe_sp'], ['penyakit_tepung', 'spaerotheca_sp'], ['hawar_daun', 'cylindrocladium_sp'], ['hawar_daun', 'phaeophleopspora_sp'], ['hawar_daun', 'kirramyces_sp']]`


but, it should be **Expected Array** above.

Comment: @AlvianSupriadi Your `output` and `Expected Array` both are different. Please add the `qres` data

Comment: qres is the object from result of SPARQL

Answer (score 0):

The general approach I take is to create a dictionary mapping each key to a list.

Say your input list looks like this:

```
[
 ['a', 'A'], ['a', 'B'], 
 ['b', 'D'], ['b', 'E'],
 ['a', 'C']
]
```

What I would do is:

```
map = {}
for item in input:
    key, value = item  # destructuring assignment
    if not key in map: map[key] = []  # initialize a spot for the key if not seen before
    map[key].append(value)
```

Now we should have a map that looks like this:

```
{'a': ['A', 'B', 'C'], 'b': ['D', 'E']}
```

Comment: how to print that map ?

Comment: @AlvianSupriadi  Isn't it easier to use Google for that basic question?!

Comment: @AlvianSupriadi Do you want every little step to be spoon fed to you? Please don't use StackOverflow to find people to do your homework for you.